# pywinauto find an exact tray item

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to create an automated GUI test framework for a desktop application and I am using pywinauto for this.
My problem is that even using SWAPY and Winspector I still have problems detecting the tray area and finding my app there.

I have tried everything from the current documentation and also tried the Volume example from the web to no success.

```
from pywinauto import taskbar

sti = taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.WrapperObject()

print 'Clicking ', sti.Button(0).info.text
sti.Button(0).Click()
```

Technically the only thing i need is finding the exact position of the tray icon and executing a click on it to bring up a menu.

pywinauto has some functions related to the taskbar but i wasn't able to get them to work.

Could anybody give me any ideas on how to do this?

**EDIT**

I tried your idea Vasily but I am getting this error:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import taskbar

app = pywinauto.application.Application()
app.start_('C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp.exe')
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'MyApp')[0]
window = app.window_(handle=w_handle)

texts = taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.Texts()
print texts
```

and the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nicolae.farcas/Desktop/pywinauto_c1.py", line 9, in <module>
    texts = taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.Texts()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1932, in Texts
    btn_text = self.GetButton(i).text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1914, in GetButton
    button.idCommand)
RuntimeError: GetButtonInfo failed for button with command id 0
```

I'm using Windows 7 Pro x64 right now but I need this to also run on 8, 8.1 and 10 (I can drop 10 since I imagine support for it is still behind)

Comment: Do you use pywinauto 0.5.1 on **64-bit** Python?

Comment: no, i use a 32 bit one

Comment: Process `explorer.exe` containing taskbar is 64-bit on 64-bit OS. You need 64-bit Python. I will think about warnings in taskbar module.

Comment: Do you see warnings about incorrect bitness in your script output?

Comment: I sometimes see warnings such as these: WARNING! Cannot retrieve text length for handle = 198548
WARNING! Cannot retrieve text length for handle = 66940
WARNING! Cannot retrieve text length for handle = 131878

Comment: Those are the only warnings I get but not all the time but from what I read, you will make them disabled by default in 0.5.2

Comment: OK, you use pywinauto 0.5.0. Please upgrade to 0.5.1. Your case is not so simple because `explorer.exe` is 64-bit, but your app looks like 32-bit. You can try 64-bit Python anyway, but with care. We thought about 32-bit apps support from 64-bit Python+pywinauto, but we don't have so much time yet.

Comment: The installed pywinauto is 0.5.1, my question is, should I try your option with a 64 bit Python?

Comment: Yes, please try 64-bit Python.

Comment: Ideal way is running taskbar specific code in 64-bit Python and then launching 32-bit Python for separate app specific script. It's not so convenient but should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use pywinauto 0.5.1, please call `taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.Texts()` and then copy corresponding text to the following call:

```
taskbar.ClickSystemTrayIcon('button text', exact=True, double=True)
```

For hidden area use `ClickHiddenSystemTrayIcon(...)`.

Also please note that popup menu belongs to your application process. So you need to connect to the application and call `app.PopupMenu.MenuItem('item name').Click()` or `ClickInput()`.

If it doesn't work, please provide error output and OS version.

EDIT:

(comment about Python 32/64 bit problem)

Ideal way is running taskbar specific code in 64-bit Python and then launching 32-bit Python for separate app specific script. It's not so convenient but should work.

Comment: When i enter command taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.Texts() i get -> user promoted notification area. How does this command work taskbar.ClickSystemTrayIcon('button text', exact=True, double=True)?
Vasily Ryabov

Comment: Just take a look at [the source code of taskbar.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/taskbar.py#L31) Not tested for Win10 though.

Comment: Hello Vasily, I was able to open the my application but using the command taskbar.ClickSystemTrayIcon("Application name") from system tray but I now I am  confused how to interact with the opened window. Any suggestion??

Comment: To get basic concepts of pywinauto read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) first.